# Looking for user manual or eeprom instructions set for PN544 NFC chip

Tags: android, nfc, rfid, eeprom

i would like to use the [mfoc library](http://code.google.com/p/nfc-tools/) with my Galaxy Nexus phone but some methods are missing in the NFC Android API. So I would like to implement those methods and build my own ROM.

With the NFC pn512 chip, it was possible to switch off the automatic parity generation using the ManualRCVReg register’s ParityDisable bit. The [user manual](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/PN512.pdf) gives all the PN12 register addresses.

With the pn533, it was also possible to configure the chip through the eeprom and some addresses/data are described in the [user manual](http://www.nxp.com/documents/user_manual/157830_PN533_um080103.pdf).

In the code of libnfc-xp in android source, I see that the pn544 chip is also configured with some eeprom settings in device/samsung/tuna/nfc/nfc_hw.c, but I can't find all the PN544 register addresses and some comments in the nfc_hw.c are unclear or missing).

So, do you think it is possible to configure the parity handling of the PN544 chip with its eeprom settings? Do you know the address/data I need to write?

It will be nice to have a list of the possible eeprom settings or an user manual for the PN544 chip.

Answer (score 1):

The PN544 user manual is only available under NDA, I think. Besides that, it is not possible to perform the kind of analysis you want to do using a PN544. The host interface only handles complete bytes, which is not detailed enough for that purpose.

Comment: Ok... Maybe the user manual will be public someday (like PN53x). Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 1):

have a look to http://www.nfc.cc/technology/nxp-nfc-chips/